# django-rest-framework custom writable field in a modelserializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have something like

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tz = serializers.Field()

    class Meta:
        model = Post

        fields = ('id', 'url', 'user', 'date', 'show', 'body', 'role', 'image', 'images', 'lat', 'lng', 'tz')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'user', 'created', 'meta', 'date_utc')
```

My end goal is to pass in a timezone into the tz field and then set the date to be a datetime with a timezone associated with it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please add the Post model definition as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

[Django supports timezone aware dates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) but [most of the backends store   `datetimes` in UTC](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#database). If you're using one of those then you can store the timezone as you suggest. You can then map this back to DRF's [SerializerMethodField](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields.html#serializermethodfield).

Perhaps something like:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...
    local_datetime = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_local_datetime')


    ...
    def get_local_datetime(self,obj):
        return pytz.timezone(obj.tz).localize(obj.datetime)
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: According to the docs SerializerMethodField is read-only: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#serializermethodfield

Comment: @andybak — yes it is. But the question has the actual date as read-only too. The only thing that's writable is the timezone. A computed `local_datetime` property would combine the two.